# Error exporting data from Google Cloud Bigtable

Tags: export, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

While going through the [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/exporting-importing#export-bigtable), I'm getting the below stack trace on the final export command (executed from the master instance with appropriate env variables set).

`${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop jar ${HADOOP_BIGTABLE_JAR} export-table -libjars ${HADOOP_BIGTABLE_JAR} <table-name> <gs://bucket>`

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hbase-install/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2016-02-08 23:39:39,068 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Export: versions=1, starttime=0, endtime=9223372036854775807, keepDeletedCells=false
2016-02-08 23:39:39,213 INFO  [main] gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.4.4-hadoop2
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.localSupportedSignAlgs from class sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:278)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getBucket(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1599)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getItemInfo(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1554)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.getItemInfo(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:547)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getFileInfo(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1042)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.exists(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:383)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configureBuckets(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1650)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.configureBuckets(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:71)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configure(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1598)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:783)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.<init>(DynamicClassLoader.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.<clinit>(ProtobufUtil.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.convertScanToString(TableMapReduceUtil.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(TableMapReduceUtil.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(TableMapReduceUtil.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(TableMapReduceUtil.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(TableMapReduceUtil.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.IdentityTableMapper.initJob(IdentityTableMapper.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export.createSubmittableJob(Export.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export.main(Export.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:153)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Here's my ENV var set up in case it's helpful:

```
export HBASE_HOME=/home/hadoop/hbase-install
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop-install

export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xbootclasspath/p:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/bigtable/alpn-boot-7.1.3.v20150130.jar"
export HADOOP_BIGTABLE_JAR=${HBASE_HOME}/lib/bigtable/bigtable-hbase-mapreduce-0.2.2-shaded.jar
export HADOOP_HBASE_JAR=${HBASE_HOME}/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.jar
```

Also, when I try to run `hbase shell` and then `list` tables it just hangs and doesn't fetch me the list of tables.  This is what happens:

```
~$ hbase shell
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hbase-install/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2016-02-09 00:02:01,334 INFO  [main] grpc.BigtableSession: Opening connection for projectId mystical-height-89421, zoneId us-central1-b, clusterId twitter-data, on data host bigtable.googleapis.com, table admin host bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com.
2016-02-09 00:02:01,358 INFO  [BigtableSession-startup-0] grpc.BigtableSession: gRPC is using the JDK provider (alpn-boot jar)
2016-02-09 00:02:01,648 INFO  [bigtable-connection-shared-executor-pool1-t2] io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor: Refreshing the OAuth token
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.1.2, rcc2b70cf03e3378800661ec5cab11eb43fafe0fc, Wed Aug 26 20:11:27 PDT 2015

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
```

I've tried:

- Double checking ALPN and ENV variables are appropriately set
- Double checking hbase-site.xml and hbase-env.sh to make sure nothing looks wrong.

I also even tried connecting to my cluster (like I was previously able to following [these](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-shell) directions) from ANOTHER gcloud instance, but it seems like I can't seem to get that to work now either...(it also hangs)

```
user@gcloud-instance:hbase-1.1.2$ bin/hbase shell
2016-02-09 00:07:03,506 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-02-09 00:07:03,913 INFO  [main] grpc.BigtableSession: Opening connection for projectId <project>, zoneId us-central1-b, clusterId <cluster>, on data host bigtable.googleapis.com, table admin host bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com.
2016-02-09 00:07:04,039 INFO  [BigtableSession-startup-0] grpc.BigtableSession: gRPC is using the JDK provider (alpn-boot jar)
2016-02-09 00:07:05,138 INFO  [Credentials-Refresh-0] io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor: Refreshing the OAuth token
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.1.2, rcc2b70cf03e3378800661ec5cab11eb43fafe0fc, Wed Aug 26 20:11:27 PDT 2015

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
Feb 09, 2016 12:07:08 AM com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.TransportSet$1 run
INFO: Created transport com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport@7b480442(bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com/64.233.183.219:443) for bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com/64.233.183.219:443
```

Any ideas with what I'm doing wrong?  Looks like an access issue - how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: We are going to update the page to use Dataproc.  In the mean time, you might try adding the netty-tcnactive jar.        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.33.Fork7</version> to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the response @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel, but I still can't seem to access my cluster from the hbase shell.  I downloaded the jar you specified and set it as part of my CLASSPATH (export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jar/netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork7.jar) and reran the shell.  Still seems to hang.  Did I do it wrong?  Also, more importantly, any pointers on how to fix my first issue (exporting data from the table, rather than just accessing it from hbase shell).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: A colleague mentioned that this doesn't appear to be a Bigtable issue, but a GCS one.  com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getBucket(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1599)
We've asked someone on that team to see if they can give some advise.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel: `myuser@bigtable-instance-m:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: That's what we thought - it appears that alpn-boot might not be compatible.  I need to update my Dataproc sample https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/wordcount-mapreduce to use Netty TCNative, but if that worked, then you'd have hbase shell on the controler and be able to do your export.  We are also working on releasing a fix to the client from 0.2.3 to 0.2.3.1 -- later today or tomorrow.

Comment: For the time being, we've rolled back to 0.2.2

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel.  Using the cloud-bigtable-examples link you posted I am able to connect to a dataproc master and run `hbase shell` and access my table (e.g. describe, scan, etc).  However when I run export command (`bin/hadoop jar bigtable-hbase-1.0-0.2.2.jar export-table -libjars bigtable-hbase-1.0-0.2.2.jar table gs://bucket`) the job seems to progress but fails with this error: 'The input format instance has not been properly initialized. Ensure you call initializeTable'.  Any ideas?  Worst comes to worst should I just scan and save the entire table to a file, then upload to gcloud?

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel - thanks, sent you an email and we can continue from there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can spin up a Dataproc cluster w/ Bigtable enabled following [these instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/wordcount-mapreduce).
2. **ssh** to the master by `./cluster.sh ssh`
3. `hbase shell` to verify that all is in order.
4. `hadoop jar ${HADOOP_BIGTABLE_JAR} export-table -libjars ${HADOOP_BIGTABLE_JAR} <table-name> gs://<bucket>/some-folder`
5. `gsutil ls gs://<bucket>/some-folder/**` and see if **_SUCCESS** exists.  If so, the remaining files are your data.
6. `exit` from your cluster master
7. `./cluster.sh delete` to get rid of the cluster, if you no longer require it.

You ran into a problem with the weekly java runtime update, that has been corrected.