# Google Cloud Bigtable HBase shell connectivity hangs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, alpn

To start, I think this issue is related to the issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281764/error-exporting-data-from-google-cloud-bigtable). However, the fix for HBase shell connectivity suggested in comments did not work for me either, and I see no resolution.

Connecting to my Bigtable cluster from the HBase shell just hangs on any command. Example:

```
ubuntu:/opt/hbase-1.1.2# ./bin/hbase shell
2016-02-29 13:43:38,975 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-02-29 13:43:39,114 INFO  [main] grpc.BigtableSession: Opening connection for projectId [removed], zoneId us-central1-b, clusterId [removed], on data host bigtable.googleapis.com, table admin host bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com.
2016-02-29 13:43:39,191 INFO  [BigtableSession-startup-0] grpc.BigtableSession: gRPC is using the JDK provider (alpn-boot jar)
2016-02-29 13:43:39,516 INFO  [bigtable-connection-shared-executor-pool1-t2] io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor: Refreshing the OAuth token
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.1.2, rcc2b70cf03e3378800661ec5cab11eb43fafe0fc, Wed Aug 26 20:11:27 PDT 2015

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
```

The shell just hangs there indefinitely and does this on any command entered.

Here are the results CheckConfig utility:

```
ubuntu:/opt/hbase-1.1.2# ./bin/hbase com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.CheckConfig
User Agent: bigtable-hbase-1.1-0.2.2
Project ID: [removed]
Cluster Id: [removed]
ZoneId: us-central1-b
Cluster admin host: bigtableclusteradmin.googleapis.com
Table admin host: bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com
Data host: bigtable.googleapis.com
Attempting credential refresh...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.localSupportedSignAlgs from class sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:278)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1093)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:222)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.CheckConfig.main(CheckConfig.java:68)
```

Here are the relevant versions and environment variables:

> ```
> Linux ubuntu7 3.19.0-30-generic #34~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:09:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> java version "1.7.0_95"
> export ALPN_VERSION=7.1.3.v20150130
> export HBASE_CLASSPATH="$(pwd)/lib/bigtable/bigtable-hbase-1.1-0.2.2.jar"
> export HBASE_OPTS="${HBASE_OPTS} -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Xbootclasspath/p:$(pwd)/lib/bigtable/alpn-boot-${ALPN_VERSION}.jar"
> ```

I'd appreciate any solutions/advice/hints at resolving this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wish to use our [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart) for HBase Shell access - It should just work. (Take a look at the hbase-site & hbase-env after running quickstart to see how to configure in the future)

The 1.7.0_95 release of Java is incompatible w/ alpn-boot.  We are moving all of our samples to use [netty-tcnative-boringssl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static/1.1.33.Fork13) see the [Managed-VM-GAE](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/managed-vm-gae) example for additional info.

Comment: Thanks @Les Vogel. I used the manual hbase shell setup instructions and must have missed the note on compatible versions. I'll give the quick start a try, as well as a java 8 version.

Comment: Java 7 works with the netty-tcnactive-boringssl artifact as well.